# I'm trying to render this sample data (measurements) from an external API however the empty elements get's rendered as well. how can I exclude it?

Tags: reactjs

```
> import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

function App() {
  const measurements = [
    '1 cup ',
    '1 large',
    '1 large',
    '1 tbs',
    '2 tsp',
    '1 tsp ',
    '1/2 tsp',
    '1/2 tsp',
    '1/4 tsp',
    '1/4 tsp',
    '4 cups ',
    '1 cup ',
    'Pinch',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' ',
  ];

  const flattenArray = (str) => {
    return str?.map((char, i) => {
      return char? (i < str.length - 1 ? char + ',' : char + '.') : null;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Measurement: {flattenArray(measurement)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

// result rendered as: 1 cup ,1 large,1 large,1 tbs,2 tsp,1 tsp ,1/2 tsp,1/2 tsp,1/4 tsp,1/4 tsp,4 cups ,1 cup ,Pinch, , , , , , , .

// expected result: 1 cup ,1 large,1 large,1 tbs,2 tsp,1 tsp ,1/2 tsp,1/2 tsp,1/4 tsp,1/4 tsp,4 cups ,1 cup ,Pinch.

Comment: The quickest option is probably just to `.filter()` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) your array to remove any empty/whitespace items.

Answer (score 1):

`.map` method always returns as many array elements as it got. If you don't need empty elements they must be filtered,

```
measurements
   .filter(item => item.trim().length > 0)
   .join(', ')
   .concat('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 const flattenArray = (str) => {
    return str?.map((char, i) => {
      return char===' ' ?null: (i ===0 ? char : ","+char ) ;
    }) ;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Measurement: {flattenArray(measurements)}.</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You have just written your own weird kind of `.join()`.

Comment: Yeah i didn't see your answer first so i want to help him